# getaddrinfo - возвращаемые данные о порте по доменному имени

Tags: c++, c, сокет, winsock, winsock2

Вопрос собственно касается функции getaddrinfo:
Вот код вызова getaddrinfo:

```
char my_char_HOST[] = "ru.stackoverflow.com";
char my_char_NAME_SERVICE[] = "https";
 
    ADDRINFOA my_ADDRINFOA;
 
    memset(&my_ADDRINFOA, 0, sizeof(my_ADDRINFOA)); 
    my_ADDRINFOA.ai_family = AF_INET;     
    my_ADDRINFOA.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; 
    my_ADDRINFOA.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
 

    struct addrinfo *servinfo;  // Сюда getaddrinfo - заносит возвращенную информацию
 
    INT my_getaddrinfo = getaddrinfo(my_char_HOST, my_char_NAME_SERVICE, &my_ADDRINFOA, &servinfo);
```

1. Судя из описания rfc3493 - ai_family выполняет некую функцию "фильтрации", то есть оно работает так, когда я запрашиваю у DNS информацию об IP-адресе по имени хоста, то DNS возвращает эти адреса, предположим у какого то сайта google.com – есть адрес и в Ipv4 и в Ipv6, то если указать к примеру только AF_INET, то DNS вернет только адреса Ipv4, если AF_INET6, то только адреса Ipv6.
2. А вот с ai_socktype и ai_protocol - не понятно, потому что они точно не аналогичную ai_family функцию выполняют, потому что, если я к примеру указываю при вызове getaddrinfo:

   ```
   my_ADDRINFOA.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; 
   my_ADDRINFOA.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
   ```

   То в возвращенной заполненной структуре addrinfo - фигурируют те же значения полей, и если я изменяю их на:

   ```
   my_ADDRINFOA.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM; 
   my_ADDRINFOA.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;
   ```

   То возвращаются уже эти значения.

   Из rfc я так и не понял назначения, но судя по результату могу предположить, что параметры ai_socktype и ai_protocol - служат указанием для getaddrinfo - по какому протоколу обращается к DNS-серверу. Вот может кто знает так это или нет ?
3. И тоже самое касается второго параметра функции getaddrinfo - это номер службы или номер порта. Если я передаю NULL, то, когда я смотрю поле структуры sockaddr_in.sin_port, там указано 0.
   Если я меняю с NULL, к примеру на "80", то в sockaddr_in.sin_port указано 80.

   То ест опять не понятно, просто повторяются те значения, которые я сам же и внес.
   Но, а, как тогда вообще узнать, как номер порта соответствует запрашиваемому доменному имени ? То есть, по какому порту мне делать запрос на сервер ?

Comment: А DNS не предоставляет информацию о портах. Стучитесь на порт по-умолчанию.

Comment: user7860670, а что за порт по умолчанию ?

Comment: например 443 для https

Comment: user7860670, так а что получается я должен минимум два раза на обум послать запросы ? на 80 или 443. Это как то несерьёзно получается.

Comment: Тем не менее, так оно и работает.

Comment: Почему два раза? Если хотите https, то на 443, если http то на 80.

Comment: Alexey Ten, у меня есть только доменное имя: stackoverflow.com, и функция getaddrinfo, которая возвращает мне заполненную структуру с IP-шником. Но, как я в рантайме узнаю порт, по которому подключатся к stackoverflow.com ?

Answer (score 4):

Третий параметр `getaddrinfo()` называется `hints` (`pHints`), т.е. это некие «подсказки» службе имён, какие адреса искать и возвращать. Важно также иметь в виду, что `getaddrinfo()` представляет собой абстрактный интерфейс, который может поддерживать разные службы имён, не только DNS и не только в ip-сетях, например, обычно, он возвращает также имена из `/etc/hosts` (`windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`), а может также использовать и другие службы для поиска хостов: `mdns`, `wins` и др.

Также удобство `getaddrinfo()` в том, что его ответа (`struct addrinfo`) вполне достаточно для создания сокета и установки соединения (`socket()`/`connect()`), т.е. `ai_family`, `ai_socktype` и `ai_protocol` можно передавать напрямую в `socket()`, а `ai_addr` и `ai_addrlen` в `connect()`.

1. Да, всё примерно так и есть. `ai_family` должно использоваться и используется на практике, чтобы ограничить возвращаемые адреса конкретным семейством протоколов.
2. Гипотетически, `ai_socktype` и `ai_protocol` также могут использоваться для фильтрации, как и `ai_family`, но я не смогу назвать службу, которая это поддерживала бы (хотя это в принципе и возможно). Так что на практике они применяются исключительно, чтобы инициализировать соответствующие значения в возвращаемом векторе `servinfo`.
3. Второй параметр — это не обязательно номер порта, это может быть и имя службы. Например, `https`, как в примере выше, — в таком случае `getaddrinfo()` просто ищет порт соответствующий данной службе аналогично `getservbyname()` (только без вероятности гонки).

   > Но, а, как тогда вообще узнать, как номер порта соответствует запрашиваемому доменному имени? То есть, по какому порту мне делать запрос на сервер ?

   Доменному имени соответствует только адрес, а порты ему «соответствуют» все: от `1` до `65535`.

   Запрос нужно делать на конкретный, заданный пользователем/оговорённый сервером порт. Есть стандартные порты для конкретных служб, обычно если порт не указывается пользователем, то запрос делается на один из таких, для этого собственно можно и указать имя службы, например `https`. Проверить, предоставляет ли данный хост конкретную службу на конкретном порту можно только установив соединение (вообще говоря, есть некоторые другие «хакерские» способы, но все они всё равно подразумевают отправку каких-либо данных на удалённый сервер).

Comment: Fat-Zer, у меня есть только доменное имя: stackoverflow.com, и функция getaddrinfo, которая возвращает мне заполненную структуру с IP-шником. Но, как я в рантайме узнаю порт, по которому подключатся к stackoverflow.com ? Не в ручную же это в коде вбивать. А Пользователь вообще не должен о опртах думать, у него есть только имя - stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @Optimus1, одного доменного имени принципиально недостаточно: нужно заранее знать к какой службе или на какой порт подключаться. На условном `stackoverflow.com` может быть несколько служб, которые используют разные порты: `https` сервер на `443`-м, `http` для обратной совместимости на `80`-м, `ssh` для админов на 22-м и т.д.… В зависимости от того, что именно ты пытаешься сделать, можно или задать номер порта явно, или использовать стандартный порт соответствующий конкретному имени службы (БД для списка известных служб есть в каждой ОС), или запросить его у пользователя...

Comment: Fat-Zer, спасибо, но я почему то всегда думал, что данная информация тоже должна предоставляется. Иначе - это фактически перебор, пусть в моем случае всего из двух служб, но это именно перебор портов. Неужели в браузере так же устроено, то есть если обычный пользователь вводит название сайта - браузер сначала пробует подключится по 80 порту, а потом, если неудачно по 443 ?

Comment: @Optimus1, да, так же, только в современных браузерах по умолчанию всё с точностью до наоборот: сначала производится попытка подключения на 443-й, а затем на 80-й... в эпоху до https браузеры всегда подразумевали 80-й порт... плюс в браузерах всегда можно указать службу явно, набрав `https://`, а также задать конкретный порт, добавив его в конец: `:8080` ... ЗЫ: Если ты собираешься делать какие-либо запросы через WebAPI и не собирашься реализовывать весь http/ssl стек самостоятельно, то `getaddrinfo()`, скорей всего, не тот интерфейс, который должен представлять интерес...

Comment: Fat-Zer, реализовываю через WInsock, поэтому http - придётся разбирать самостоятельно.